# Connect virtual machines

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have a Linux machine with an IP address (for example `172.16.x.x`). With some hosted virtual machines, each machine is accessed with different `ssh` port (eg 2230, 2234...).

For instance in **VM1** I have an Apache server which load the view and I want to connect to `redis` server hosted on **VM2**.

The `redis` server works fine on port 6739, when I execute `netstat` I get the following output::

```
$ netstat -ntlp | grep 6379 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

However, when I do the same command on the Apache VM, I get nothing and the program can't load from the `redis` DB.

How do I make a bridge between those Ubuntu VMs ?

Comment: Hello learner, welcome to Super User. What exactly are you asking? I started to edit this question but quickly realised I couldn't do much substantial to make it clearer- could you edit it to clarify what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve? I see there is an answer- can you verify that this addresses what you are attempting? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your redis server is only listening on the localhost interface. Therefore it can be only acessed from its own host. Let it listen to all network interfaces by using `0.0.0.0`. See the second answer here for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537254/redis-connect-to-remote-server

Comment: You're a braver and smarter man than I for making sense of that question.